# Eclipse C++ - cannot resolve string type

Tags: c++, eclipse, string

I'm trying to build a header file, prog1.h, which currently looks as follows:

```
#ifndef PROG1_H_
#define PROG1_H_

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int NUMGRADES = 5;

struct StudentInfo{
    string id;
    double avGrade;
    int grades[NUMGRADES];
};

int ReadGrades(istream & input, StudentInfo Info[]);

void HighestAverage(StudentInfo Info[], int numStudents, string & id, double & maxAv);

#endif /* PROG1_H_ */
```

However, the string identifier is underlined and Eclipse says that "string cannot be resolved to a type". I included everything and am using the standard namespace, so what's the problem?

Thank You!

Comment: You shouldn't throw `using` statements into the global namespace, especially in header files.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing std::string and removing the using.